# How to manipulate cross domain iframe with javascript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have cross domain iframe that is displaying some content and images. i am trying to manipulate some divs and css on iframe.

is it possible to manipulate iframe with javascript or JQuery ? or any other way ?

Thanks

Comment: *Is it possible"* .. No, unless you control the code in both pages. Read up on [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)